# compute expression for values of three dictionaries with similar keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have three dictionaries with similar keys, whose values i would like to do some computing with.

```
dict1 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
dict2 = {key1: 10, key2: 10, key3: 10}
dict2 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
```

How can I use python to find a dictionary with the result of:

```
dict1.values() / ((dict2.values() - dict3.values())*100)
```

i'm looking for the result like so:

```
resultdict = {key1: .00111111, key2: .0025, key3: .00428571}
```

I had succeeded in doing a calculation with two dictionaries in the following way, but I'm confused about how to include a third:

```
finaldict = {}
for key in (dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys()):
    if key in dict1: finaldict.setdefault(key, []).append(dict1[key][0])
    if key in dict2: finaldict.setdefault(key, []).append(dict2[key])
for lst in finaldict.values():
    if not lst[0] == 0:
        lst[0] = (float(lst[1]) / float(lst[0]))*100
        del lst[-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the keys in `dict1` are the same as the keys in `dict2` and `dict3`, this should be an easy solution to follow:

```
dict1 = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}
dict2 = {'key1': 10.4, 'key2': 10, 'key3': 10}
dict3 = {'key1': 10.4, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}

finaldict = {}
for key in dict1.keys():
    denom = float(dict2[key]) - float(dict3[key])
    if denom == 0.0: # or denom <= 0.0
      continue # skips over 'key1' because it can't do division by 0
    finaldict[key] = dict1[key] / (denom * 100)

print finaldict 
#  {'key3': 0.004285714285714286, 'key2': 0.0025}
```

Comment: What would be a good way to ensure this only runs if the denominator is not zero?

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly easy to think about if you use a dict comprehension, like this:

```
finaldict = { k: float(dict1[k]) / ((dict2[k]-dict3[k])*100) for k in dict1}
```

The expression on the right-hand side of the `=` is a dict comprehension. It creates a diction and populates with the results of the loop. In our case, we loop on all of the keys `for k in dict`. The key:value pairs are calculated according to your formulate: `k: dict1/dict2...`.

Complete program:

```
key1, key2, key3 = 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
dict1 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
dict2 = {key1: 10, key2: 10, key3: 10}
dict3 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
finaldict = { k: float(dict1[k]) / ((dict2[k]-dict3[k])*100) for k in dict1}
print finaldict
```

Or, if you are concerned that the key lists might differ, use the intersection (`&`) of the key views. This will produce a `set` that lists only the keys in common.

```
key1, key2, key3 = 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
dict1 = {'extra': 42, key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
dict2 = {key1: 10, key2: 10, key3: 10}
dict3 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}

keys = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys() & dict3.viewkeys()
finaldict = { k:float(dict1[k]) / ((dict2[k]-dict3[k])*100) for k in keys }
print finaldict
```

Of course, sometimes the single expression of a comprehension isn't sufficient. You can always switch back to a loop:

```
key1, key2, key3 = 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
# Note: dict2[key3]==dict3[key3], which will cause a divide-by-zero error.
dict1 = {'extra': 42, key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
dict2 = {key1: 10, key2: 10, key3: 3}
dict3 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}

finaldict = {}
for k in dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys() & dict3.viewkeys():
    try:
        finaldict[k] = float(dict1[k]) / ((dict2[k]-dict3[k])*100)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass  # Skip divide-by-zero errors!
print finaldict
```

Comment: What is the importance of the line key1, key2, key3 = 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'? And how can I avoid an error in the case that the denominator is 0? I appreciate your response.

Comment: @Rob I forgot to tag you in my previous question

Comment: @Rob I'm also wondering about my result, which is set([value1, value2, value3]) and not a dictionary. how can I keep my keys intact?

Comment: @user25976 - The set problem is my fault. The penultimate line in the 2nd example should be like `finaldict = { k : float(dict1... }`. Notice the `k:` was missing before my edit.

Comment: @user25976 - re: "denominator is 0". See my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

Rob has already mentioned how to find the value, but the one thing that you need in addition is how to get the keys which are common. You can try the following technique:

```
In [240]: allK = map(set, map(lambda m: m.keys(), dicts))

In [241]: allK
Out[241]: [{'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}, {'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}, {'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}]

In [242]: reduce( lambda m, n: m&n, allK  )
Out[242]: {'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}
```

Then, use these keys instead of the keys from dict1 as mentioned by Rob.

## EDIT:

Forgot to mention,

```
dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
```

You will need to do this. And if you are feeling particularly lazy with a largish number of dictionaries, and they are numbered in the neat manner you have described, you can always cheat:

```
In [247]: eval( '[' + ', '.join([ 'dict%d'%i  for i in range(1,4)]) + ']' )
Out[247]:
[{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3},
 {'key1': 10, 'key2': 10, 'key3': 10},
 {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}]
```

Comment: Or, `set.intersection(*(set(d.keys()) for d in dicts))`.

Comment: In-place expansion with list comprehension. Thats neat. Thanks!